# Android application talking to Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, python, server, raspberry-pi, webserver

I currently have a Python script on a Raspberry Pi that will check the WiFi for my phone and when it does it turns on my smart light.

I am thinking of making an Android app that can change the settings for the light when I come home. I want this app to be able to tell it, for example, to be red when it comes on. I want the script to be changed every time the settings for the light are changed on the app.

I have almost no experience in this kind of stuff where an app can talk to a Pi. I have a Pi Zero that I thought I could put a server on and talk to the other Pi, but I do not know if that would be too many steps. I was thinking of a web server, but again I am lost and would like some direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a too broad question to be answered on SO.

I understand you are not familiar with Andriod development and so you should first learn to develop Android apps before going forward.

What you can do at this point is to install a web server on the RP and send HTTP commands to it that will trigger python scripts to change the settings.
Once your backend is ready you should try and use already existing apps to issue those commands. 
I'm not sure what you can use but a couple are [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) and maybe [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) could help too.
Hope that gave you a direction.